# Error: Could not find or load main class com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark, openfire, instant-messaging

I am trying to install spark client IM in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, but it throws error

```
Could not find or load main class com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher
```

I performed step 1 from this link https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-setup-im-voip-server-using-openfire-ubuntu-1404 but it still shows same error.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

This error is occurring because the hidden directory `.install4j`  was not moved to `/opt/spark/`  after you have made the command: `mv  Spark/* /opt/spark/`   by terminal in  `/tmp`. 
Make the display of hidden files  in `/tmp/Spark`. Inside the directory `/tmp/Spark`  you must do the following command:

```
mv .install4j/ /opt/spark/
```